# Cointegration between 2 Stocks. - confirming Times Series Stationarity using ADF & KPSS Test

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I had created a google sheet with the help of online resources, - to conduct cointegration test on 2 stocks time series. It checks null hypothesis, to see that a unit root is present on the residual between linear regression any 2 stocks time series.
Pl. refer google sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r0_oHLTcT9tmTJPgKVgkGwGWhooBM8uluwmWcC92eOk/edit?usp=sharing
For ADF, It compares T-stat of Delta X & lagged X with critical Value at (10%, 5 % & 1%).
[image]

I seek clarity for the process of KPSS test. In order to check stationarity of the residual series - the series selected in ADF is Delta X (daily change in the diff. between predicted Stock B value & actual StockB value) & lagged X.
Do I need to select same series (Delta X & lagged X) or do we need to select time (date range of time series) and ratio (i.e. StockA / StockB), inorder to check stationarity of residual.
[image]

The incomparability in ADF and KPSS results, created doubt on the results.

Seek attention of the Statistics experts (as I am not).
If more info reqd. do let me know.

Comment: Reading that output is very difficult. A KPSS test for cointegration has been published by Shin (Econometric Theory 1994), it has different critical values, just like the Engle-Granger test has c.v.s different from ADF. Even having said that, there is, surely in finite samples, nothing that says that these tests' results cannot contradict each other.

Comment: Hope Adding graph to the series will help..??